# addrindex patch bitcoin core. it does not show unconfirmed tx

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I'd like to ask about addrindex patched bitcoin core by btcdrak. The diff between bitcoin core and the patch is the following.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/compare/0.13...btcdrak:addrindex-0.13

My question is that searchrawtransactions RPC command does not retrieve my unconfirmed tx even though addrindex=1 is set and bitcoin-cli getrawmempool retrieve the tx.

The unconfirmed tx is retrieved by getrawmempool.

```
$ bitcoin-cli getrawmempool | grep 90e225e60dc36f3d323ffcf6897858e056681b8a9e015ee4371558c7b1f0241f
  "90e225e60dc36f3d323ffcf6897858e056681b8a9e015ee4371558c7b1f0241f",

$ bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction 90e225e60dc36f3d323ffcf6897858e056681b8a9e015ee4371558c7b1f0241f
 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
```

However, searchrawtransactions does not retrieve the tx.

```
$curl --user 'xxx:xxx' --data-binary '{"jsonrpc":"1.0","id":"curltext","method":"searchrawtransactions","params":["12sWrxRY7E7Nhmuyjbz4TtGE9jRewGqEZD", 1, 0, 100000]}' -H 'content-type:text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:xxxx | grep 90e225e60dc36f3d323ffcf6897858e056681b8a9e015ee4371558c7b1f0241f
```

Have you ever seen this issue? I tried it on addrindex version 0.12.1 and 0.13.2.

I'm sure that unconfirmed txes are showed normally before. The recent high mempool size might be the cause.

I already posted this issue on github but I did not get answer for now. I need to fix it as soon as possible. So I posted this question here too. https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/issues/20

Answer (score 1):

I am not a dev, so I can't tell for sure, but it appears addresses are indexed as they enter the blockchain.

> I'm sure that unconfirmed txes are showed normally before.

How do you know? I mean, maybe you used this on a server where the state was different, and compared against a server which hadn't received the block by that time?

EDIT: see this https://www.bountysource.com/issues/6995691-jmcorgan-address-index-not-updated-immediately-upon-tx-broadcast